# Link Table - How to get a list of items in list

Tags: sql

I have a link table called AccountGroupLinks.  It has two columns:

- AccountId
- GroupId

For each of the groups assigned to account X, get a distinct list of accounts assigned to each group excluding group Y.  I can't seem to figure this SQL statement out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a self join to do this:

```
select distinct t2.GroupId, t2.AccountId
  from AccountGroupLinks t1
  join AccountGroupLinks t2
    on t2.GroupId = t1.GroupId
   and t2.GroupId <> 'Y'
 where t1.AccountId = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sstan.  I was trying to do nested select statements. This got me on the right direction. I had to make a small tweak to get it to work:

```
select distinct t2.GroupId, t2.AccountId
  from AccountGroupLinks t1
  join AccountGroupLinks t2
    on t2.GroupId = t1.GroupId
   and t2.GroupId <> 'Y'
   and t2.accountId <> 'X'
 where t1.AccountId = 'X'
```